# How to filter for user registration, be able to throw error message

Tags: filters, hooks, user-registration

I'm setting up a woocommerce/woprdpress site.  Upon checkout, a user is created in the system. I want to take the user data and create the user in our external systems (both proprietary db and auth0).

If any of the external systems reject the user creation (user exists/bad password etc.) I want to be able to reject the user registration AND display the error message to the user.

So far I've seen 2 relevand hook/filter options:

- `register_post` hook - I can add data to the errors list. But I don't get all the user info and password I need to create the user in the external systems
- `wp_pre_insert_user_data` filter - I get everything, but I have no way of triggering an error to be displayed. I can return null and then the generic error 'Not enough data to create this user.' will be displayed, no way to control it.

Is there any way to achieve what i'm looking for?

Comment: Did you try `registration_errors()` filter for your purpose? Here is a visual guide of registration hooks - https://usersinsights.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/user-registration-hooks-2.png

Comment: @anton the `registration_errors` filter (or `woocommerce_registration_errors` in my specific use case)  only receives the username and email. I need all user data including the password

Comment: This question is intersting for me to, will need to do the same thing later. On developers website for this hook I see an example where someone checks fields directly from `$_POST` array. Guess after registration_errors() filter will be to late to register errors anyway.